# Do I need server code in order to edit server files remotely?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, nginx

I have a web server with an xml file that at some point is going to hold the information for posts on the website. This is the xml's structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<posts>
 <post>
  <date>7/9/2013 6:44 PM</date>
  <category>general</category>
  <poster>elfenari</poster>
  <title>Test Post</title>
  <content>This is a test post for the website</content>
 </post>
</posts>
```

I created an applet using swing in netbeans, with this as the code to create the xml from the UI objects in the applet.

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(url.openStream());

            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
            Element ePost = doc.createElement("post");
            Element eDate = doc.createElement("date");
            eDate.setTextContent(time);
            Element eCategory = doc.createElement("category");
            eCategory.setTextContent(category);
            Element eTitle = doc.createElement("title");
            eTitle.setTextContent(title);
            Element ePoster = doc.createElement("poster");
            ePoster.setTextContent(poster);
            Element eContent = doc.createElement("content");
            eContent.setTextContent(post);

            ePost.appendChild(eDate);
            ePost.appendChild(eCategory);
            ePost.appendChild(eTitle);
            ePost.appendChild(ePoster);
            ePost.appendChild(eContent);
            root.appendChild(ePost);

            TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            trans.transform(source, result);
            String xmlString = sw.toString();

            OutputStream f0;
            byte buf[] = xmlString.getBytes();
            f0 = new FileOutputStream(url);
            for(int i=0;i<buf .length;i++) {
                f0.write(buf[i]);
            }
            f0.close();
            buf = null;
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(xGrep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(xGrep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I've done some research, and I think I need a java program on my server to accept the change to the xml, but I'm not sure how exactly to do that. Could you tell me what I need to edit the file on the server, and how to code something if I do need it?